# Can't remove app icons from the desktop

Tags: adw.launcher

I installed AdwLauncher. In the beginning it worked well.

But now, I can't delete the app icons from the desktop.

The situation is that when I longpress the desktop, the list doesn't show up so that I can't add shortcuts, apps or widget to the desktop.

Also, when I longpress the app icon on the desktop, list doesn't show up so that I can't remove, delete or edit the icon.

My cellular is HTC Desire. Is this a bug problem or I just set up in a wrong way?

Restarting the phone didn't help.

I used "home switch" to change the launcher back to HTC sense, then changed back to ADW but it still remains the same.

Comment: does restarting ADW (or the phone) helps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you accidentally locked the Desktop?  The option to "Unlock Desktop" should be on the Menu (possibly under the "More" option).